# Is it possible to create a new column when returning an SQL result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server table containing a `TEXT` column and a `DATETIME` column .

I'm trying to write a stored procedure which will return the `TEXT` column and a BIT (0 or 1) depending on whether the date/time is less than the current timestamp.

Does anyone know the correct syntax? I've tried the following, but no luck.

```
SELECT ticket, (ticketExpires < getDate()) 
FROM Authentication 
WHERE accountID = @id
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, your syntax would work in MySQL but not SQL Server, so you were kind of on the right track.

Comment: I'm migrating the application from MySQL. For better or worse :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ticket,
  CONVERT(Bit, CASE WHEN (TicketExpires < getDate())
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END) IsExpired
FROM Authentication
WHERE accountID = @id;
```

You'd change the return value based on whether you're looking for a value that indicates `IsExpired` or `IsValid`.

Comment: I think your answer would be improved by adding a column alias to the column in question.  The syntax is something like inserting an alias like "expired" after the close paren.  But that may be Oracle syntax.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks ever so much.

Comment: @WalterMitty I have given it a column alias - `IsExpired`. I could have written `AS IsExpired`, but the `AS` keyword is optional with T-SQL and I believe ANSI SQL in general.

Answer (score 0):

Use the case statement to return 1 or 0. I use them extensively!